# Mongodb update with $concat and field missing

Tags: mongodb

I wanted  to update a collection  to  set a  new Field  with  other  inner field
it looks like to  generate a person's full name .

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.name.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7ca743c45316e35251a49e"), "first" : "Don", "middle" : "Jhon", "last" : "Trump" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7ca75bc45316e35251a49f"), "first" : "Dila", "last" : "Tp" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7ca76dc45316e35251a4a0"), "first" : "Li", "last" : "Wei" }
```

I  want  to set the full name with `$first` +`$middle` + `$last`  in One 
 update
I  try to  use update  with an aggregation pipeline. this is a new feature in mongodb 4.2

```
 db.name.updateMany({},[{$set:{full:{$concat: [ "$first", "$middle","$last" ] }}}])
```

but this result  return a lot  of  null value  when some  field  is missing  .

```
db.name.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7ca743c45316e35251a49e"), "first" : "Don", "middle" : "Jhon", "last" : "Trump", "full" : "DonJhonTrump" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7ca75bc45316e35251a49f"), "first" : "Dila", "last" : "Tp", "full" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7ca76dc45316e35251a4a0"), "first" : "Li", "last" : "Wei", "full" : null }
```

Comment: Try this `db.name.updateMany({},[{$set:{full:{$concat: [ "$first" || "", "$middle" || "","$last" || "" ] }}}])`

Comment: @matrixersp  not  working  but it  gave me a lot of tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) function. Rewrite your query like this

```
db.name.updateMany({},[{$set:{full:{$concat: [ {$ifNull:["$first", ""]}, {$ifNull:["$middle", ""]},{$ifNull:["$last", ""]} ] }}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I  also  try use  with  `$cond` it  also  worked  but  more  complicated

```
db.name.updateMany({},[{$set:{full:{$concat: [ "$first", {"$cond" :{if :{$gt:["$middle", null]},then :"$middle" ,else :""}},"$last" ] }}}])
```

put  it here  to help  others  if needed .